# Uploading a file to a database using JSP

Tags: java, database, oracle, jsp, blob

I know a little to 0 Java, and I was able to upload certain files into a database using some data streams; however, someone told me to do the same using JSP, and I'm completly lost!

I have no idea about this, I've killed myself searching for a solution.

What's the best way to do this?

I have a pdf file and I'm supposed to get this file stored into an oracle database... as far as I know I have to create a blob field in a table. But how do I get a file from my computer stored into a database server?

Comment: Continuing the *//...(do your job here)* part, refer to [Java SE 6: Blob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/blob.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html), the usage page provides some good example on how to use it.